# $K\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is compact, show that $K \subset K(r,\delta) $

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with natural topology. Let $K\in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ compact set and $K \subset \bigcup _{n\in \mathbb{N}}K(r_{n},1)$, where $K(r_{n},1)$ is open ball (in Euclidean metric). Show that exists $r\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\delta>0$ such as $K\subseteq K(r,\delta)$

My solution is:

So if $K$ is compact, then:

1) $K$ is Hausdorff space,

2) from every open cover there is a finite subcover.

Now, $\bigcup _{n\in \mathbb{N}}K(r_{n},1)$ is finite cover of $K$. As we know, $K$ is compact, so there exists finite subcover of $\bigcup _{n\in \mathbb{N}}K(r_{n},1)$, $r\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\delta>0: K(r,\delta)$

We concude that:

$K\subset \bigcup _{n\in \mathbb{N}}K(r_{n},1) \subset K(r,\delta) $

Am I correct?

Comment: $K\color{red}{\in}\Bbb R^n$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not say what $r$ and $\delta$ are. Take $r=0$ and $\delta=1+\max \{\|r_i\|: 1\leq i \leq n\}$. Note that $x \in K$ implies $\|x-r_i\| <1$ for  some $i$. This gives $\|x-0\| \leq \|r_i\|+\|x-r_i\|<1+\|r_i\| <\delta$.

Comment: Can I take $r=0$? Such ball does not exist?

Comment: @Michal By $r=0$ I mean $r =(0,0,...,0)$. This vector belongs to $\mathbb R^{n}$ so $K(r,\delta)$ exists for any $\delta >0$.

Comment: Forgive me, for a second I thought $r$ was radius...
Thanks for clarification.